# flutter: is it best practice code to fetch list of posts?

Tags: api, dart, flutter

My Flutter Code to fetch posts from API is:

```
Future<List<Posts>> fetchPosts() async {
var url = 'https://*****.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": 'application/json'});
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setState(() {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var p in jsonData) {
        Posts post = Posts(
          id: p['id'],
          date: p['date'],
          title: p['title'],
          link: p['link'],
          postViews: p['views'],
          featuredImage: p['featured_image'],
          featuredImageBig: p['featured_image_big'],
          categories: p['categories'],
          comments: p['comments'],
          content: p['content'],
        );
        posts.add(post);
      }
    });      
} 
}}
```

I ask is it best practice code  to fetch list of posts ?

thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a Class called Post:

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final String link;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;

  Post(this.id, this.link, this.imageUrl, this.title);

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Post(json['id'], json['link'], json['imageUrl'], json['title']);
  }

  static Future<List<Post>> get(int skip, int take) async {
    var response =
        await Api.get('api/v1/posts?SkipCount=$skip&MaxResultCount=$take&');

    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    final items = (responseJson["items"] as List).map((i) => new Post.fromJson(i));

    return items.toList();
  }
}
```

The only other thing you need it the Api class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Api{
  static const String BaseUrl = 'http://yourapiwebsite.com/';

  static Future<http.Response> get(String url){
    return http.get(BaseUrl + url);
  }
}
```

This can handle all of your normal calls. If you are intending to pass dynamic parameters from UI to the API, you can have a bloc and get the parameter from it.

Comment: Thank you (Siavash) very much that what i need

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i think you don't return anything in your function. Also the variable posts, which i guess is a List doesn't exist inside of your function. So I would change it like this:

```
Future<List<Posts>> fetchPosts() async {
    List<Posts> posts = [];    

    var url = 'https://*****.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';
    final response = await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": 'application/json'});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        for (var p in jsonData) {
          Posts post = Posts(
            id: p['id'],
            date: p['date'],
            title: p['title'],
            link: p['link'],
            postViews: p['views'],
            featuredImage: p['featured_image'],
            featuredImageBig: p['featured_image_big'],
            categories: p['categories'],
            comments: p['comments'],
            content: p['content'],
          );
          posts.add(post);
        }
      });
    }

    return posts;
  }}
```

This implementation is good for a small scale application. When the scale of your application increases, and you might support different kind of requests and such kind, you should take a look at the Bloc pattern for best practice.

You can find an example of using the Bloc pattern together with a web API on the channel of Tensor Programming: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALcbTxz3bUw